# How to register objects of classes implementing the same interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface for mapping java beans like this

```
public interface Mapper <K,V> {
    K map(V v);
    V mapReverse(K k);
}
```

Example of an implementation

```
public class CarMapper implements Mapper<Car, CarDTO> {
    public Car map(CarDTO dto) {
         //implementation
    };

    public CarDTO mapReverse(Car car) {
         //implementation
    };
}
```

Now I want to provide a common access-point for all such implementations so that the user does not have to remember the names of all the implementations.

For example:-

```
public class MapperFacade {
    public static<K,V> K map(V v, Class<K> k, Class<V> v) {
        //1) get the appropriate mapper implementation (throw an exception if no such implementation is  found)
        //2) map the object
        //3) return the object
    }
}
```

Now there are two questions I have:-

1) How do I get the appropriate mapper implementation at run-time and know which method to call (map or mapReverse).

2) If the Mapper implementations are spread across different java projects, how do I create a framework where each mapper implementation can register itself at a central place and then can  be accessed via a common point as mentioned above

Comment: I dont think there is a way to that like you want .. but you can use a builder class .. use key and value class as aparameter to build ..

Comment: Keep a `Map<Class,Mapper>` somewhere ? Elaborate it and call it `MapperRegistry` ? A Lot of ORM's have such a facade: `Mapper<Car> = Orm.createDto(Car.class)`

Comment: You seem to be looking for the Service Provider Interface. Maybe include a command name and description in the interface methods.

Comment: If you are looking at the problem of bean conversion, why not use existing solutions like dozer bean converter. It pretty much does all the things you are asking.

Comment: @S.D. actually, i don't want to manually register the mappers. Is there a way by which the mappers can auto-register?
I need this because the mapper implementations might be spread across multiple java projects.

Comment: @ishan3243 For automatic scan and register at runtime, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recently solved this problem myself using spring.
Here is the solution

First, refactor the Mapper interface as:-

```
public abstract class Mapper <Entity, DTO> {
    private static final MapperFactory mapperFactory = MapperFactory.getInstance();
    public Mapper() {
        mapperFactory.registerMapper(getEntityClass(), getDTOClass(),this);
    }

    public abstract Entity map(DTO object);
    public abstract DTO mapReverse(Entity object); 

    public abstract Class<Entity> getEntityClass();
    public abstract Class<DTO> getDTOClass();
}

public class MapperFactory {
    private Map<String, Mapper> mappers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //MapperFactory is a singleton class, ConcurrentHashMap ensures thread safety.         

    private static final MapperFactory INSTANCE = new MapperFactory();

    public static MapperFactory() {
        return MapperFactory.INSTANCE;
    }

    public <Entity, DTO> void registerMapper(Class<Entity> entityClass, Class<DTO> dtoClass, Mapper<Entity, DTO> mapper) {
        mappers.put(dtoClass.getCanonicalName(), mapper);
        mappers.put(entityClass.getCanonicalName(), mapper);
    }

    public <T> Mapper getMapper(Class<T> sourceClass) {
         mappers.get(sourceClass.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

For a common interface for accessing all the mappers, use this class:-

```
public class MapperFacade {
    private MapperFactory mapperFactory = MapperFactory.getInstance();

    public <Entity, DTO> DTO entityToDTO(Entity entity, Class<DTO> dtoClass) {
        Mapper<Entity, DTO> mapper = mapperFactory.getMapper(entity.getClass());
        return mapper.mapReverse(entity);
    }

    public <Entity, DTO> Entity dtoToEntity(DTO dto, Class<Entity> entityClass) {
        Mapper<Entity, DTO> mapper = mapperFactory.getMapper(dto.getClass());
        return mapper.map(dto);
    }
}
```

Now for auto-registering any mapper, we can use @Component annotation of spring. eg:-

```
@Component
public class CarMapper <Car, CarDTO> {
    public Car map(CarDTO carDTO) {
        //impl
    }

    public CarDTO mapReverse(Car car) {
        //impl
    }

    public Class<Car> getEntityClass() {
        return Car.getClass();
    }
    public Class<CarDTO> getDtoClass() {
        return CarDTO.getClass();
    }
}
```

So now you don't have to care about what the mapper classes are and don't need to register them by yourself in some initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but how about something like this. Register the mappers in maps using the classes as keys. A more complete implementation would use isAssignable checks, not just an exact class match. In case the values being mapped are subclasses of the base class.

```
public class MapperFacade<K,V> implements Mapper<K,V> {
    private Map<Class<K>,Mapper<K,V>> keyMappers = new HashMap<Class<K>,Mapper<K,V>>();
    private Map<Class<V>,Mapper<K,V>> valueMappers = new HashMap<Class<V>,Mapper<K,V>>();

    public void addMapper(Mapper<K,V> mapper, Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
        keyMappers.put(keyClass, mapper);
        valueMappers.put(valueClass, mapper);
    }

    public K map(V value) {
        Mapper<K,V> mapper = valueMappers.get(value.getClass());
        return mapper.map(value);
    }

    public V mapReverse(K key) {
        Mapper<K,V> mapper = keyMappers.get(key.getClass());
        return mapper.mapReverse(key);
    }
}
```

or make the map methods "less magical" by supplying the class, as in your code (MapperFacade wont implement Mapper any longer)

```
    public K map(V value, Class<V> valueClass) {
        Mapper<K,V> mapper = valueMappers.get(valueClass);
        return mapper.map(value);
    }

    public V mapReverse(K key, Class<V> keyClass) {
        Mapper<K,V> mapper = keyMappers.get(keyClass);
        return mapper.mapReverse(key);
    }
```

This assumes there is one mapper per class. If there could be multiple mappers for the same class, you may need to use a single HashMap but a bean for the key which consists of both `Class<K>` and `Class<V>` - Or two Maps of Maps…

```
    private Map<Class<K>,Map<Class<V>,Mapper<K,V>>> keyMappers = ...
    private Map<Class<V>,Map<Class<K>,Mapper<K,V>>> valueMappers = ...
```

Comment: what about if maps has same key value class or same value  class ?

Comment: yep, just thought of that. i added this to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You're reimplementing Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). Use that.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How do I get the appropriate mapper implementation at run-time and
>   know which method to call (map or mapReverse).

To explore meta level info at runtime, you can try something like [Reflectons](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

It allows you to "query" class definition metadata at runtime:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
```

So, the lookup table for finding the right implementation of `Mapper` can be dynamic. But please be sure about pros and cons of this approach. Specially how you are going to maintain classes.

> 2) If the Mapper implementations are spread across different java
>   projects, how do I create a framework where each mapper implementation
>   can register itself at a central place and then can be accessed via a
>   common point as mentioned above

If the final program is an integration of all these sub projects (that is, compiled as one), then nothing special needs to be done, other than scan the class-paths using above approach. Otherwise if these sub-projects run in separate environments (remote), then you have to explore [more approaches.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/classloaders-140370.html)